# Chart Visualization on Databricks

Tags: graph, databricks, graph-visualization

I am trying to create a chart with double axis showing both a percentage value and a absoute value.

Just Like that:

[image]

My issue here is that I cant find a way to choose the data type on the second image:

[image]

Does anyone knows hot to?

Answer (score 0):

I think it does glitch sometimes, if you keep adding columns to the series until you can see that under data labels, it should resolve it. Later you can remove unnecessary columns.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).